# SQL Query INTERSECTS - Relational Algebra

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

I am trying to convert the following 2 relational algebra into standard english but I am having trouble understand what exactly the INTERSECTS does

I know that INTERSECT finds the values that occur in both select statements

I have managed to find its SQL query, but I just can't figure out what it asks in plain english

Would anyone be able to help?

**Relational Algebra:**

```
Πstudent_name(σcourse id=“CS1850“(student Natural Join enrolled)) ∩
Πstudent_name(σcourse id=“CS1840“(student Natural Join enrolled))
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT student_name FROM student NATURAL JOIN enrolled WHERE 
course_id='CS1850' INTERSECT SELECT student_name FROM student 
NATURAL JOIN enrolled where student_name='CS1840'
```

**Second Expression:**

```
Πstudent_name(σe1.student   
id=e2.student_id∧e1.course_id<>e2.course_id(student natural join 
(ρe1(enrolled) × ρe2(enrolled))))

SELECT student_name FROM student NATURAL JOIN enrolled e1 NATURAL JOIN  
e2 WHERE e1.student_id = e2.student_id
```

Comment: In human language: "Find all students enrolled in 'CS1850', and find all students enrolled in 'CS1840', and return the intersection of those two result sets", or "Find all students enrolled in *both* 'CS1850'  and 'CS1840'."

Comment: @JimmyB - I understand - any ideas about the second one?

Comment: The second SQL does not match the algebraic expression. It lacks the `e1.course id<>e2.course`.

Comment: I tried my best to convert from expression to query - where am I going wrong?

Comment: In human language: "Find all students who are enrolled in one course and at the same time are enrolled in a course different from the first.", or "Find all students enrolled in at least two different courses."

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is an error waiting to happen.  It matches tables based on the *names* of columns in common.  It doesn't even use properly declared foreign key relationships.  Instead, use `USING` or `ON` to be explicit about the columns used for joining.

Second, you don't need `INTERSECT`.  There are two typical methods that use `GROUP BY` or `JOIN`.

In English, the query gets the students that are enrolled in both classes.

```
SELECT s.student_name
FROM student s JOIN
     enrolled e
     USING (student_id) -- or whatever
WHERE e.course_id IN ('CS1850', 'CS1840')
GROUP BY s.student_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes that two students do not have the same name.

An alternative just uses `JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.student_name
FROM student s JOIN
     enrolled e1
     USING (student_id) JOIN
     enrolled e2
     USING (student_id)
WHERE e1.course_id = 'CS1850' AND
      e2.course_id = 'CS1840';
```

If the underlying tables do not have duplicates, then this doesn't need a `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`.

Comment: How does the Query above or your query differ from doing **WHERE course_id='CS1850' AND course_id='CS1840'**?

Comment: @RandomMath . . . My query will return students in both classes.  Your `WHERE` clause will always filter out all students (because `course_id` cannot take on both values in the same row).

Comment: Oh I understand - My expression did completely upload - there is also another advanced query above which I am unaware of translating to english